# Jenkins Github pull Request Builder phrase update

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using DSL script to create a Github Pull request build job. I am trying to modify phrase "retest this please" to "retest". I can find all other phrase in Plugin UI like skipphrase, Test phrase. Accept to test phrase (in manage jenkins) or job config, but not able to find this "retest this please". if you can share DSL or groovy code that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

triggerPhrase('^.*retest.*$') worked for me.